# Activate a default virtualenv when starting a terminal (using bashrc)

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

The default python version in my system is 2.6.6.  I installed virtualenv, and I want the default virtualenv to be 2.7 whenever I open a terminal.

So, I added the following command in the ~/.bashrc file:

```
source $HOME/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/activate
```

Now whenever I start a terminal by clicking the icon in Gnome environment (i.e., I've already logged into the machine and open a new terminal window (xterm) inside Gnome), the shell symbol looks like this:

```
    (py2.7)(py2.7)
```

It looks like somehow I have a virtualenv inside another virtualenv.  Even worse, I can only deactivate the one virtualenv but not the other, as demonstrate below:

```
    (py2.7)(py2.7)deactivate 
    (py2.7)python
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 28 2013, 14:53:08) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> exit()
    (py2.7)deactivate
    bash: deactivate: command not found
    (py2.7)python
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 28 2013, 14:53:08) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>
```

As you can see, although the default python in my system is 2.6, I am stuck at the virtualenv (2.7)

If I switch to a text virtual console by Ctrl + Alt + F2 and login, it looks normal.

```
    (py2.7)[username@host ~]$
```

I can deactivate and go back to the system's default python 2.6.

```
    (py2.7)[username@host ~]$ python
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 28 2013, 14:53:08) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> exit()
    (py2.7)[username@host ~]$ deactivate
    [username@host ~]$ python
    Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48) 
    [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>
```

What's the problem?  Is it possible to set the default virtualenv to 2.7 whenever I open a terminal in Gnome?

My Linux distribution is RedHat 6.

Comment: sourcing bin/activate changes your $PATH so its first entry is the virtualenv’s bin/ directory.This is all it does; it’s purely a convenience. Try skipping the sourcing directive and just fiddle with the PATH-environment variable instead. You might see the issues you are seeing if you source your .bashrc twice...

Comment: PS. I added the sourcing directive at the bottom of my `.bashrc` and started a new bash-terminal and it behaves as expected (i.e it works). Tested on ubuntu 12.04. What do you mean by "clicking the icon in Gnome environment"?

Comment: you need [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in your life

Comment: @FredrikPihl: I just edited the original post to make it clear.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

How about this? To test if you are already within a virtualenv :)

```
test -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" && source $HOME/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 5):

Wolph's answer did not work for me. Instead I used following test in my .bashrc:

```
if (tty -s); then
    source /pathto/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/activate
fi
```

tty exits with 0 if standard input is a terminal and 1 if it is not. If you do not test this, it somehow is executed twice: once when logging in and additionally when you open a terminal.

**Edit:** If you do "screen" now, you will again get 
(py2.7)(py2.7)user@computer ]$

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to use [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) which is really convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and then similar to [Godrebh's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28171350/111363), I just call my preferred default virtualenv in my `.bashrc` (or other login script).

```
if (tty -s); then
  workon py3_default
fi
```